# How to forward traffic from one IP to another IP address

Tags: server, forward, web-traffic

We have two identical servers A and B in our office. These two servers are synced together in all aspect. That's if some changes take place in one server then it will take effect in another server. This has been done to minimize the downtime. Now server A has a public IP address (X.X.X.X) form one ISP. Server B has a public IP address(XX.XX.XX.XX) from a different ISP. Now for some reason IP address X.X.X.X goes down. **Now How can we automatically forward traffic to another IP address so website will not go down?**

Answer (score 1):

You're basically asking about high availability, you'd have a third server (called load balancer) in front which would sent traffic to either server based on their status. Have a look at a simple setup [in here.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/what-is-high-availability)

Comment: Thank you for your valued reply. In my case using load balance will not work as the Internet connections are from two separate ISP. Now if one Internet connection goes down, how client browser know about new IP address? Because DNS will resolve to one IP address at a time. As MX records has priority number to check whether first IP address for mail exchange is available or not and so on. I don't know whether it is available for A records.

Answer (score 0):

can you use DNS-level fail over using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html